# Parse string to Date Java

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, simpledateformat

I have a database that saves a date in string. 
Before saving it to my db, I put the date in format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` with SimpleDateFormat. 
I manage to fetch the String from my db and the format is correct.

My problem is when I try to set my Calendar with the setTime() function I require a Date. So basically I need to convert the String sent by my database into the Date format. When I try to do so I get ParseException error

Here is an example:

```
   private Calendar c;
   private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
   private String myDate;
   private Date d; 


   myDate = db.getDate() //This works I output correct date 
   d = dateFormat.parse(date); // Error Message : Unhandled Exception: java.text.ParseException
   c.setTime(d); //Needs Date Format to set time
```

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, it will give you the option to automatically surround that in a try catch

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error, IDE (Android Studio) is asking you to handle the `exception` to prevent run time `exception`. Include that in `try` `catch` block:

```
try {
        d = dateFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```